# VSS2005: how to use labels to allow quick compiling of earlier versions of code?

Tags: version-control, visual-sourcesafe, label, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Using Visual SourceSafe 2005, what do I need to do to tell VSS 2005 that the current version of code should be labelled (or whatever) so that after further revisions I can come back later and get the version of code that was labelled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How to: Label an Item* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e8x236w(VS.80).aspx, making sure you select a project/folder on the left side pane.

**To label the current version of a file or project:**

1. In Visual SourceSafe Explorer, select the file or **project** to label.
2. On the File menu, click Label.
3. In the Label dialog box, enter descriptive text in the Label box.
4. Optionally enter a comment for the label in the Comment box.
5. Click OK.

<strike>*How to: Label an Item Using a SourceSafe Plug-in* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zz3bhef7(VS.80).aspx (Which I did not know.)</strike> [This does not work.]

**To get the latest version by Label**

In the *How to: Label an Item* topic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e8x236w(VS.80).aspx) there is a link to the *How to: Get an Item to Your Working Folder* (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh8hd2cw(VS.80).aspx) that describes how to get the latest version of a file or project and the latest version by label:.

Comment: @missico: how do you then "get" all files for the project that have a specific label on them?

Comment: @Craig Johnston: You need to start helping yourself more.

Comment: @Amissico: you mean by not using VSS anymore?

Comment: @John Saunders: You funny. A regular programmatic-comedian. No, by asking questions that take more time then looking up the answer.

Comment: @AMissico: that's explicitly permitted on SO.

Comment: @John Saunders: "explicitly"? I missed the part. In my opinion, Craig Johnston is taking advantage, because..."Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask."